# get value of field from an embedded pdf

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf

I want to edit and update a PDF file in a browser window and then get the values of the updates and save them to sql.

I have embedded a PDF file into a ASP.Net page (has MasterPage). I have 2 different ways of embedding the object. (Embedding is not the issue).

```
<iframe runat="server" id="iframe1" class="embIframe" width="810px" height="500px" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" data-id="123456789"></iframe>
```

And

```
<embed runat="server" class="emb" id="Embed1" width="810px" height="500px" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" />
```

I realized that I will have to do this using Javascript, but I am not so good at it.

There are the variations of I have tried. (Although i have tried many many more)

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('<%= iframePDF.ClientID %>');
var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

var form = doc.getElementById('pdfEmbed');
var pdf = form.exportAsObject(); // I get error here
var formData = JSON.stringify(pdf);





var iframe = document.querySelectorAll(".embIframe");
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var formFields = iframeDoc.querySelectorAll('input[type=text], input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio], select, textarea'); // I get error here


var pdfDocument = document.querySelectorAll(".emb");
var formFields = pdfDocument.getJSAPI().getFieldObjects();// I get error here

 var pdfObject = document.querySelectorAll(".emb");
alert("The value of the form field is: " + pdfObject.value);
var pdfDoc = pdfjsLib.get;// I get error here
```

I cannot seem to get the value of the form fields or even target the embedded document.

Please help.

Comment: You create a form with a submit button and submit FDF to a server. This is XML that can be processed

Comment: @KevinBrown Is there no other way?